# 3d schrodinger equation weak form

Tags: parabolic-pde, complex-analysis, weak-solution, galerkin

### SCHRODINGER’S EQUATION

$$-ih u_{t}(x,y,z,t) = \frac{h^2}{2m} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)+ \frac{e^2}{r}u(x,y,z,t)$$
The potential $\frac{e^2}{r}$ is a variable coefficient.
So, let’s take the free Schrodinger equation $$-i u_{t}(x,y,z,t) = \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)$$
in three dimensions, where we’ve set $h = m = 1$ and dropped the potential term. It looks like the diffusion equation.

\begin{align*}
-i u_{t}(x,y,z,t) &= \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)\\
-i u_{t}(x,y,z,t) - \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)&=0\\
\end{align*}
and also setting $k = \frac{i}{2}$ we have the equation:
$$ u_{t}(x,y,z,t) - k u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)=0$$
or : $$ u_{t} - k \Delta u =0 $$

with $$u=0, \quad \text{in}\quad \partial \Omega$$
In the weak form :
Let $v \in H'_{0}(\Omega)$

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega}u_{t}v dV - k \int_{\Omega}\Delta u v dV&= 0 \\
\int_{\Omega}u_{t}v dV -k \int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV& - k\int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}v dS &= 0 \\
\int_{\Omega}u_{t}v +k\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV &=0 
\end{align*}

The problem is how I treat the  $\frac{i}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions of the Schroedinger equation are complex-valued, so your inner product needs to be
$$
  (u,v) = \int_\Omega \bar u(x) v(x)\; dx,
$$
and the norms then become
$$
  \|u\| = (u,u)^{1/2}.
$$

But it is also worth pointing out that you shouldn't think of the Schroedinger equation as a variation of the heat equation that just happens to have an imaginary diffusion coefficient. In reality, the Schroedinger equation is more akin to a wave equation. I have written the argument for this up in one of the deal.II tutorial programs here: https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_58.html (Isn't it funny how there is a deal.II tutorial for nearly every purpose? ;-) )

Comment: Thanks for the hint.I am just experimenting around with fem

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth "Isn't it funny how there is a deal.II tutorial for nearly every purpose? ;-)" Yes